# Added Auto-Number field in Managed Package - How to generate values for existing records in upgraded orgs?

Tags: managed-package, field-update, push-upgrade

I have a managed app installed in multiple orgs. This app contains CustomObject__c. All org where my app is installed have many records of that type.

Now I push upgraded this app and added a new Auto-Number field for CustomObject__c. The records that already existed before upgrade didn't get assigned a value for this Auto-Number fields.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Good question, I suspect the answer is you cannot. Based on this answer I found, there is an option when you create the field, but that is of course no good for packaged solutions! :( http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000HZsrEAG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile it is not possible to add auto number fields after a managed package is released.
You immediately get this error message:

> Auto number fields cannot be added to a custom object when the custom
>   object has already been uploaded in a Managed - Released package.

[image: Screenshot Error Message]

Answer (score 3):

As Andrew Fawcett mention in his comment the answer is simple: you can't. Outside of managed packages you can by switching the field to a text field, but this isn't possible in a managed context.

[I wrote up a blog post about my frustations with auto-number fields](http://www.ca-peterson.com/2011/09/tales-of-isv-fear-auto-number-field.html) as an ISV a while back, it may come in handy as a warning about some of the numerous pitfalls you're sure to encounter.